# Which architecture to use for utility tokens?

Tags: bifrost, offer, anchor

Consider this scenario:

1. CoolVideo lets artists post videos and earn money from viewers
2. Viewers buy VidTokens with ETH & BTC and pay artists with VidTokens
3. We store the ETH & BTC. Never touching it except to extract our transaction fees.
4. Artists can take their earned VidTokens and redeem them for BTC/ETH (we pay out through the holding fund)
5. VidTokens will only be usable in CoolVideo (not on any exchanges)

I see a few ways of doing this with Stellar, but I can use help picking the right one.

**Idea #1 Offers**

1. We (the app) continuously create Offers as needed: ie 1000 VidToken for 0.005 BTC
2. We create the front-end that only shows those offers so users can take the offer and pay BTC/ETH
3. When a user wants to withdraw funds, we create an offer for them, and then we automatically take the offer

**Idea #2: Use Bifrost**

It seems like Bifrost can do what we need, but I'm not 100% certain

**Idea #3: Become an Anchor**

Go through the whole process of becoming an anchor and setting trust lines acting as a holding institution.

This seems like overkill, but at least I know it will do what we need where as the other ideas im not 100% certain.

What do you think?